# During acceleration, tachometer needle raises, but speedometer needle does not raise until RPM hits over 2

Tags: honda, accord, speedometer

I have a 2000 Honda Accord SE. I have noticed that when I stepped on the gas pedal after coming to a complete stop, or just starting a drive, the tachometer needle would raise while the speedometer needle stays at 0 mark. After the RPM has reached over 2, the speedometer needle will then slowly raise. Has anyone here experienced this?

Does anyone know what may be happening here? This car just had its transmission rebuilt 2 yrs ago @ 125000+ miles, and its catalytic converter replace 1 yr ago. Current mileage is 146000+. Am I facing any another big problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bad wheel speed sensor to me. That or a sticky speedometer needle.

Comment: Are you actually moving when this happens? Is this an automatic or standard shift transmission?

Comment: One other question, does the needle drop to zero as you are decreasing speed as well?

Comment: Based on my own experiences, if you have a manual transmission then the clutch might need replacement.

Comment: Actually this happens in my honda too. I always thought it is somehow related to honda engineering. I hear for some pollution control mechanism, the car wont gain burst acceleration.  For me it is about 1500 maybe

Answer (score 1):

Is the speedometer reading low? Do people regularly ride your bumper and honk at you? If so, then the speedometer needle shaft could be rusty or sticking. If the car actually doesn't move until the tach hits 2K, then I'd suspect your torque converter (or clutch, if it's a manual, but you'd probably notice that slipping at other speeds too).